# Design a one-time functional class

Tags: python, design-patterns, class-design

Imagine a class `Interpreter` that takes a `Parser` and evaluates the data yielded by the Parser into a `Document`. The Interpreter must be instantiated and is supposed to be executed immediately, with no reuse. The reason to not make it just a function is to be able to use sub-procedures during the interpretation phase (methods).

Below is a simple example of such an Interpreter class. I personally consider it bad to call `self.run()` from the constructor, but at the same time, I can not think of a better design. Can you  advise?

```
class Interpreter():

    def __init__(self, workspace, document, parser):
        super().__init__()
        self.workspace = workspace
        self.document = document
        self.parser = parser
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.parser.next()
            if not data: break
            self.interpret(data)

    def interpret(self, data):
        if data['type'] == 'statement':
            handler_name = 'statement_{0}'.format(data['name'])
            method = getattr(self, handler_name, None)
            if not method or not callable(method):
                raise SyntaxError('unknown statement {0}'.format(data['name']))
            method(data)
        elif data['type'] == 'assignment':
            self.document.define(data['left'], data['right'])
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('unexpected data from parser')

    def statement_print(self, data):
        print(*data['args'])

    def statement_load(self, data):
        if len(data['args']) not in (1, 3):
            raise SyntaxError('load statement requires 1 or 3 arguments')
        name = data['args'][0]
        dest = name
        if len(data) == 3:
            if data['args'][1] != 'as':
                raise SyntaxError('load statement second argument must be "as"')
            dest = data['args'][2]

        doc = self.workspace.load(name)
        self.document.alias(doc, dest)

    def statement_if(self, data):
        # todo: check if if-statement applies
        # ...
        next = self.parser.next()
        if next['indent'] <= data['indent']:
            raise SyntaxError('need at least one line after if-statement')
        indent = next['indent']
        while next['indent'] == indent:
            self.interpret(next)
            next = self.parser.next()
        if next['indent'] > indent:
            raise SyntaxError('unexpected indent')
        self.parser.push_back(next)
```

Comment: What does "The reason to not make it just a function is to be able to use sub-procedures during the interpretation phase (methods)" mean? Why can't you just have several functions?

Comment: I'd need to pass around `self.workspace`, `self.document` and `self.parser` to each of these function. It is not only `run()` that might need the parser, I'll update the example. Also, but not so important, is having these functions that really only work _together_ indented under a class makes it much more neat.

Comment: It might be unexpected to readers that instantiating will cause it to run; perhaps remove the call in `__init__` then use it like `Interpreter(w, d, p).run()`.